# Why does my HTML list move off the screen in a WebView?

Tags: android, html, list, webview, indentation

I'm loading some local HTML files in WebView fragments inside a ViewPager. I've been scratching my head about the indentation of the numbered list, as I increase the size of the font the list moves to the left and even moves so that it starts off the screen.

[image: Smallest font size]

[image: Next size]

[image]

[image]

This demo HTML has NO CSS associated with it:

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
        <p>This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. This is a simple paragraph. </p>
            <ol>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
                <li>Item 5</li>
             </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behavior of an HTML `ol` element. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hnum/).

The W3C recommendation for browser vendors to display `ol` elements ([Typical default display properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html#ol-display)) is:

```
ol {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  margin-before: 1em;
  margin-after: 1em;
  margin-start: 0;
  margin-end: 0;
  padding-start: 40px; 
}
```

The `padding-start: 40px;` is the interesting part here. Because the *padding* is not defined in a proportional unit (px) it is not relative to or follows the change of the *font-size*. It will always be **40px**.

So one solution would be to set the *padding-left* of the `ol` element to a proportional unit (em):

```
ol {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hnum/1/).

---

Here are three different approaches to set the *padding*:

**1. Inline style**

Use the `style` attribute:

```
<ol style="padding-left: 1.5em;">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ol>
```

**2. The `style` element**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>your title</title>
    <style>
      ol {
        padding-left: 1.5em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

**3. External style sheet**

This approach is my recommendation, because you have a clear separation between markup and styles. Link an external CSS file to your HTML document.

HTML document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>your title</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="path/to/your/css/style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS file style.css:

```
ol {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

---

Be aware of the *direction of text* in your HTML document. If you have a right-to-left direction you should set the *padding-right* and not the *padding-left*. Using `<html dir=ltr>` or `<html dir=rtl>`, respectively, you can go with this:

```
[dir=ltr] ol {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

[dir=rtl] ol {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: I'm astonished to find that you're right about the issue but I can't use the em values as you've done as the text size is being set from the WebView fragment: webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);

Comment: You don't have to set the font size. That was just to visualize the problem. You just need the `padding-left` (respectively `padding-right`) for the `ol` element. I added three different approaches to my answer to set the *padding*.

Comment: You misunderstand, I need to be able to set the font size using that method but I don't have access to the CSS from the code to be able to set things dynamically so I need a CSS that will work for multiple font sizes. Is that possible?

Comment: @Leon I would think if you set the size of the font and use `em` units in the css, it would work properly.  `em` changes the value to scale with the font size set.  `setDefaultFontSize` uses sp units, which don't exist to css.  Since this is the case, it would stand that the size *is* converted to something the browser can understand, obviously :).  When the font size changes, the browser will reparse the css and the `em` units will be re-calculated.

Comment: @FabianMebus I have been away and come back to this and now it all seems to be working. Must have been caching the old CSS at the time. Thanks for your help